# Cannot pass arguments from html to view function

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-urls

I have been banging my head, over this problem for a day now.

I am using the Django [`password_reset_confirm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py) view to handle password change requests from a user.

I am getting an error as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8as3i.png).

```
Reverse mismatch for 'password_reset_confirm'
```

This is my html which renders the form.

```
<div>
    <h1></h1>
    <form id='reset-password-form' action="{% url 'password_reset_confirm'  uidb64=uidb64 token=token %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form|foundation }}
        {{title}}
        {{validlink}}
        <div id='submit-button'>
            <input type="submit" id='submit-reset-form'>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The url mapping is like this:

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',password_reset_confirm, {'set_password_form':ResetPasswordForm,'template_name':'email/password_reset/password_enternew_password.html',}
    ,name='password_reset_confirm')
```

Can anybody tell me, where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `uidb64` and `token` are not passed to the template context, so you cannot use them in the url tag.

The easiest fix is to remove the action attribute from the form. That will prevent the reverse match error, and the form will submit to the current url, which is correct.

If you look at the code for the [password reset confirm template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b78226cd3d2dd578ac57341e0c55754b31ab66ba/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_confirm.html) included with the `django.contrib.admin` app in the master branch, you can see that it doesn't have an action attribute. Earlier versions of Django had `action=""`, but this is invalid in HTML5.

Comment: but password_reset_confirm takes uidb64 and token as arguments, shouldn't the argumennts be passed from the template itself ?

Comment: according to the docs, password_reset_confirm can fetch the user information from the link clicked, and give a good reference link .

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question before. See my updated answer.

Comment: if action attribute is not added in the form tag, how would the form be submitte d ?.

Comment: If the form doesn't have an action attribute, it will submit to the current url (which already contains the `uidb64` and `token`) automatically.